# HTML.Partial - MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have problem with returning a partial view from a controller with different model than my main View. For example:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //myModel - get Some Types
        return View(mymodel);
    }

    public PartialViewResult Categories()
    {
        //my another Model - get different Types

        return PartialView(myanothermodel);
    }
```

And then in Index View:

`@Html.RenderPartial("Categories")`

I get an exception saying that it is of the wrong type. It expects first type(mymodel) instead of second type.

Is it possible to return different types for view and its partial view?
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to render the *action*, not the view.

Call `@Html.Action("Categories")`.

Comment: Why `@Html.Action`? and does the `PartialViewResult` need to change to `ActionResult`. Seems the way is just like not using partial view.

Comment: @Call: Because he wants to render an action.  No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using **Partial View** only use

```
@Html.Partial("Categories", Model)
```

or a especific Model with your own data

```
@Html.Partial("Categories", Model.Category)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just understood a bit how partial view works. In your and my case actually, no need to define the `Categories()` action if you think the logic to get `myanothermodel` can be done in `Index()` action.

So I have `mymodel.myanothermodel` assigned in the `Index()` action and then in the strongly typed `Index.cshtml` I used this: (assume `myanothermodel` is `Categories`)

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Categories", Model.Categories);}
```

alternatively:

```
@Html.Partial("Categories", Model.Categories)
```

Note that always use `.RenderPartial()` rather than `.Partial()` for best performance in .cshtml view. I used `Model.Categories` instead of `mymodel.Categories` because of the strongly typed `Index.cshtml` already have `@model mymodel` in the begining of the file.

In my practise I have the models like:

- `Model.Departments` - `IList<DepartmentModel>`
- `Model.SelectedDepartment` - `DepartmentModel`
- `Model.Employees` - `IList<EmployeeModel>`

which is used in:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("DepartmentMenu", Model.Departments);}

<div id="employeeViewContainner">
    @foreach (var emp in Model.Employees)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("CardView" + Model.SelectedDepartments.Name, emp);
    }
</div>
```

This will render employee list with different skin for different department.